# Transaction simulation error using phantom wallet

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

`Transaction error:  Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x92
at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (connection.ts:5921:1)
at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (connection.ts:5880:1)
at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (send-and-confirm-raw-transaction.ts:84:1)
at async w.send (provider.ts:124:1)
at async Object.initialize (rpc.ts:26:1)
at async createCounter (App.tsx:111:1)

```
      try {
        console.log("baseAccount",baseAccount)
        console.log(baseAccount.publicKey)
        const init = await program.rpc.initialize(1, {
            accounts: {
                authority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                pool: baseAccount.publicKey,
                vault: baseAccount.publicKey,
                owner: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                poolSigner: connectedPublicKey,
                systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
            },
            signers: [baseAccount],
        });

        console.log('Pool Initialized:', init);
        const account = await program.account.myAccount.fetch(baseAccount.publicKey);
        console.log('account: ', account);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your program code as well? This is not a Phantom issue, instead its coming from your Program. That would help understand this specific issue better.

Comment: Sure. 
Here's the link to the code
https://gist.github.com/sunidhii19/83cb2412516bf5a02cb440b7fcf29928

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the correct wallets and/or are they funded with sufficent Solana to preform the action you want?